# Hadoop single node cluster set up issues

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am newbie to Hadoop. I tried to do single node cluster set up and while opening Resource manager UI and job history UI, I am getting `server not found` error.

Please refer the attached image. While executing `jps` command, I am seeing following O/P:

```
5023 JobHistoryServer
5554 Jps
4631 ResourceManager
3916 DataNode
4014 NameNode
4124 SecondaryNameNode
4888 NodeManager
```

I am seeing `server not found` on these UIs: http://localhost:8088/cluster and http://localhost:19888/jobhistory.

Please assist on how to access these UIs.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you do `hdfs dfs -ls /`? Or run the map reduce examples? The web UI isn't the only way to check things work

Comment: Try by disabling firewalls (iptables)

Comment: Show us your `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, for your replies,i am able to access the UIs now.Page was displaying server not found,so i tried to check hostname on box and replaced localhost with hostname/ipaddress,finally able to access both the UIs now.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCARI.png)